# MYSQLi JOIN 2 tables and SUM of 2 columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to join 2 tables where id is the same, but in the same query I am trying to get the sum of 2 columns and then group them by id?

I have tried many different queries and they all either fail or do not give me the results I need.

Here is where I am at so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM tour_detail, SUM(Payment_Amount) AS amount1, SUM(trip_cost) AS amount2 FROM bookings INNER JOIN bookings ON tour_detail.tour_id=bookings.tour_id GROUP BY tour_detail.tour_id
```

EDIT....

Table: tour_detail

```
tour_id  | tour_title | start_date | rates | child_rate | fully_booked
----------------------------------------------------------------------
29       | Title 1    | 2017-08-17 | 3.00  | 0.50       | 0
31       | Title 2    | 2017-08-22 | 4.50  | 1.50       | 0
```

Table: bookings

```
tour_id  | adults     | childs     | Payment_Amount | trip_cost
----------------------------------------------------------------------
29       | 3          | 0          | 0.00           | 9.00      
31       | 5          | 2          | 13.00          | 26.00
29       | 2          | 1          | 3.25           | 6.50
```

I want to list all the trips and show how many adults and children are booked onto that trip. I also want to show total payment_amount and total trip_cost per trip.

So I want my result to look like this (apologies if this doesn't render right this is the first time I have posted code on here)

```
tour_id  |  tour_title  |  start_date  |  rates  |  child_rate  | fully_booked  |  adults  |  childs  |  amount1  |  amount2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29       | Trip title 1 |  2017-08-17  | 3.00  | 0.50         | 0             | 5        | 1        |   3.25       |  15.50
31       | Trip title 2 |  2017-08-22  | 4.50  | 1.50         | 0             | 5        | 2        |   13.00     |  26.00
```

Comment: Your query is rife with errors.  Please post table structure and sample data, along with the output you expect.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the info you asked for, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try computing the sums in a separate subquery and then joining:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.adults,
    t2.childs,
    t2.amount1,
    t2.amount2
FROM tour_detail t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        tour_id,
        SUM(adults) AS adults,
        SUM(childs) AS childs,
        SUM(Payment_Amount) AS amount1,
        SUM(trip_cost) AS amount2
    FROM bookings
    GROUP BY tour_id
) t2
    ON t1.tour_id = t2.tour_id
```

Comment: Thank you :) this is the query that got it working for me

    `SELECT * FROM tour_detail INNER JOIN (SELECT tour_id, SUM(adults) AS adults, SUM(childs) AS childs, SUM(Payment_Amount) AS amount1, SUM(trip_cost) AS amount2 FROM bookings GROUP BY tour_id) bookings ON tour_detail.tour_id = bookings.tour_id`